# Read the string within a line and then display the next line in a text file using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text

Using VB.Net and a text file

**For Example #1:** 10 LINES (Below are the text/data inside a text file)
Filename: Test1.txt
Note #1: I want to search the string "F1" then display the "I play Farmville" in a TextBox1.Text

FaceF1book 'line#1
I play Farmville 'line#2
'line#3
'line#4
TwitF2ter 'line#5
Occassionally use this site 'line#6
'line#7
'line#8
FriendsF3ter 'line#9
I don't want to use this site 'line#10

**For Example #2:** 12 LINES (Below are the text/data inside a text file)
Filename: Test2.txt
Note #2.1: I want to search the string "F2" then display the "Occassionally use this site" in a TextBox1.Text
Note #2.2: You can notice that the line position of the data aren't the same in the Example #1

FaceF1book 'line#1
I play Farmville 'line#2
I love to chat with my friends 'line#3
I want to be famous 'line#4
'line#5
'line#6
TwitF2ter 'line#7
Occassionally use this site 'line#8
'line#9
'line#10
FriendsF3ter 'line#11
I don't want to use this site 'line#12

Comment: Is there a question in tF3ere someF1where?

Comment: @Plutonix: Let's consider the F1, F2 and F3 are the unchangeable data in a text file and the rest of it may be replace/change... You can notice on my 2 examples same data but the other contains more data... I need to searched a specific string within a line (lets say the first line contains the string that I wanted) but instead to display the first line I want to display the second line or third line...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
    Dim dataFile As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\WindowsUser\Desktop\Test Files\test1.txt")
    If System.IO.File.Exists(dataFile) Then
        Try
            Dim lines As New List(Of String)
            lines.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile))

            Dim searchFor As String = "F1"
            For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
                If lines(i).Contains(searchFor) Then
                    ' ... do something with lines(i + 1) ... ?
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Reading File")
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(dataFile, "File Not Found")
    End If
```

Comment: Im looking for a code that get the line position of every line in a text file.. I will search for a string... lets say the string can be found in the third line in a text file then instead of displaying the whole third line which is the string was included... I want to display the whole fourth line and/or fifth line and/or six line...

Comment: Thank you for the response back. I tried to insert your code to my code but I encountered an error. Error Message: Illegal characters in path. Error in your code "lines.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile))".

Comment: Did you change the path in `dataFile` to reflect the correct path to your file?  The error indicates that the value in there is invalid...

Comment: Yes I already do that. Here's my path "C:\Users\WindowsUser\Desktop\Test Files\test1.txt"

Comment: That looks o.k. I suppose.  Try the edited code and see if it helps pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Your edited code works fine and display the whole text file data but it won't show/display the searched string declared in the code (F1). The Message Box display the File Not Found.

Comment: OK...I didn't output anything in my example.  I put in "... do something with lines(i + 1) ...".  We'd need to see what you're doing to determine how it isn't working!

Comment: The example # 1 text file contain 10 lines and then the "F1" string located in the first line. I want to display the second line which is "I play Farmville" based on the searched string the "F1".

Comment: So in the spot where I have "... do something with lines(i + 1) ...", you'd do something like `TextBox1.Text = lines(i+1)`.

Comment: I tried the code "TextBox1.Text = lines(i+1)" but still got the File Not Found display then the TextBox1.Text is still empty.

Comment: **I can't help you with the File Not Found error.**  I'm not at your computer.  YOU have to figure out what is wrong with the path you're passing to it.  Sorry.

Comment: There's no error regarding on the path of the file. It displays all the data of the text file in the VB.NET when it runs. The issue is on displaying the next line of the searched string.